# Strsplit data with partial header

Tags: r

I understand this have been asked but it's not working for me. I'm trying to split the data column pulled from FRED.

Here's what data$DGS1 looks like. You see it retrieves the date and yield into one column but I need to separate it, so I tried it with `" "` and that did not work. It gave an error `Error in strsplit(data$DGS1, " ") : non-character argument`

[image]
           DGS1
1993-10-01 3.35
1993-10-04 3.35
1993-10-05 3.38
1993-10-06 3.36
1993-10-07 3.35

Here's my code:

```
symbols=c("DGS1","DGS2","DGS3","DGS5","DGS7","DGS10","DGS20")
getSymbols(symbols,src='FRED')
data <- na.omit(merge(DGS1,DGS2,DGS3,DGS5,DGS7,DGS10,DGS20))
data <- strsplit(as.character(data$DGS1), " ")
print (head(data$DGS1, n=5))
```

When I have it as `data<- strsplit(as.character(all$DGS1), " ")`, it returns `null`. How can I split the column so I can get the dates and rates?

Comment: what would be your desired output ? The date is not part of the column, it is the index of the rows : try `index(data)` to have the vector of the dates and `as.vector(data[, 1])` for the vector of the rates.

Comment: @etienne oh wow, thank you! didn't know that.

Comment: In the following `m` is an xts object so to get its index: `m <- na.omit(merge(DGS1,DGS2,DGS3,DGS5,DGS7,DGS10,DGS20));  head(index(m))` .  Please provide reproducible code in your questions. All library calls should be included.